# Send a web page to Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

I would like to use the email option (or share option) to send the entire page or at least the URL to Google Drive. I'm trying to replace Evernote and want to be able to email a link to Google Drive instead of saving to Evernote or Dropbox. Sort of like "send to Dropbox".  I tried `www.emailitin.com` but it only sends a .txt file and even then inconsistently.

Thanks for the answers - I use "save to Google Drive" on my Windows PC but the extension doesn't work in Chrome for iOS. Need something that works on an iPad as well.

Comment: Ah. You need an iOS solution. You're probably better off asking on [apple.se] then.

Answer (score 3):

If you'd rather have a PNG of the entire web page (or the entire HTML source, or a web archive `.mht`, or have it converted to a Google document) and you use Google Chrome, the [Save to Google Drive](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-to-google-drive/gmbmikajjgmnabiglmofipeabaddhgne) Chrome extension will do what you want.

> Save web content or screen capture directly to Google Drive.
>   The Save to Google Drive Chrome extension helps you save web content or browser screenshots to your Google Drive.
>
> - Adds a browser action to save the current page.
> - Adds a right-click context menu to save hyperlinks and media.
>
> This extension allow you to save web content directly to Google Drive through a browser action or context menu. You can save links to documents, images, and HTML5 audio and video all by right clicking and selecting 'Save to Google Drive'. You can save the currently viewed page using the 'Save to Google Drive' browser action. The directory location and format of saved HTML pages can be controlled with the extension's options page (Choice of Entire image (default), Visible image, Raw HTML, MHTML, or Google Doc). You can automatically convert Microsoft Office files or comma separated files to Google Docs format.
>
> After your content is saved, the progress dialog allows you to open the file, rename, or view the file in the Google Drive document list. From the document list, you can organize and share your new document.

I use this extension quite a bit and it works really well for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to save from your mobile, you can download the appropriate gDrive app, which will add an entry to your share action list. On desktop use @AlEverett's solution or a similar extension for other browsers.

If you're looking to email, you could do something like this:

## Procedure

1. Run a script to check gmail every couple of minutes for new emails that are labeled with *GoogleDrive*, then copy the email text or attachment to Google drive.
2. Send the email to you+gdrive@google.com (note that gmail ignores anything between the + and the @)
3. Set a filter to add the label *GoogleDrive* to all emails sent to that particular email address.

## Sample Script

This script will just get the attachments and is run from a spreadsheet, but it's a starting point...

```
function sendToGDrive() {    

 var sheet   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

// Find the Gmail Label and Google Drive Folder

 var gLabel  = sheet.getRange("D4:D4").getValues();
 var gFolder = sheet.getRange("D5:D5").getValues();

// Search for any news messages with the Google Drive Label
 var threads = GmailApp.search("label:" + gLabel);
 var folder  = DocsList.getFolder(gFolder);

 for (var x=0; x<threads.length; x++) {    
  var messages = threads[x].getMessages();    
  for (var y=0; y<messages.length; y++) {      
   var att = messages[y].getAttachments();      
   for (var z=0; z<att.length; z++) {
    try {
     // Copy the Gmail attachment to Google Drive
     var file = folder.createFile(att[z]);
     // Wait for a minute to prevent timeout errors
     Utilities.sleep(1000);
    }
    catch (e) {
     GmailApp.sendEmail(
      Session.getActiveUser().getUserLoginId(), 
       "Error: " + messages[z].getSubject(), e.message);
    }
   }       
  }    
 // Message Processed; Remove the Google Drive Label
 GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(gLabel)
         .removeFromThread(threads[x]);
 }
}

// Initialize the Google Apps Script
function configure() {
 var sheet   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var gLabel  = sheet.getRange("D4:D4").getValues();
 var gFolder = sheet.getRange("D5:D5").getValues();

 if (!GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(gLabel)) {
   GmailApp.createLabel(gLabel);
 }

 var folders = DocsList.getAllFolders();
 var found = false;

 for (var i=0; i<folders.length; i++) {
   if (folders[i].getName() == gFolder) {
    found = true;
    break; 
   }
 }

 if (!found) {
   DocsList.createFolder(gFolder);
 }

 // Set a Time-driven trigger for every 5 minutes
 if (ScriptApp.getScriptTriggers().length == 0) {
   ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendToGDrive").timeBased().everyMinutes(5).create();
 }

 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  .toast("That's it. Google Docs will monitor your mailbox in the background.",
         "Close Window", -1);
}

// Create the Gmail menu in Google sheet
function onOpen() {  
 var menu = [    
  {name: "Initialize", functionName: "configure"},
  {name: "Run", functionName: "configure"}
 ];  

 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
               .addMenu("Gmail (Click here)", menu);
}
```

## References

- script by [Amit Agarwal](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/6559/amit-agarwal) (if you like it find a good answer of his somewhere and upvote it)
- [article on lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5906343/instantly-send-any-gmail-attachment-to-google-drive)
- [actual script code](http://ctrlq.org/code/19053-send-to-google-drive)

Disclaimer: I haven't tested it.

Edit: much more thorough answer, completely rewritten from being a lazy link - thanks for the nudge, Al